# VSCode's Intellisense shows autocomplete suggestions from other Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, intellisense

I run multiple Jupyter notebooks on my VSCode, and Intellisense shows autocomplete variables from other (already running) notebooks.

For example, if I declare a variable `example_var` in `Notebook1`, whenever I'll type `exa` on `Notebook2` Intellisense will show `example_var` in the autocomplete.

If I terminate the other running Notebooks, this issues goes away.[image]